# How do I sketch the solution to an IBVP of a PDE for different values of time?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given a partial differential equation, some boundary conditions, and an initial condition, how do you sketch solutions and how do you determine its steady state temperature?

Comment: ...What PDE do you mean?

Comment: @Ian any PDE. I'm asking for a general approach

Comment: There is no general approach.

Comment: @Ian see my earlier question regarding a similar problem